# Android options menu adds additional items with res/menu-v11/items.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

This is my Java code. myFrag class extends `FragmentActivity` and I have used switch case to select each item in the menu. All the other menu items show without a problem and every time the menu `actionflow` button is clicked additional items named `res/menu-v11/items.xml` are automatically added.

[image: Example]

Please also see the screen shot of how the menu items appear.Thanks in advance.

```
package com.biasharafinder.bidhaa;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class myFrag extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected boolean onPrepareOptionsPanel(View view, Menu menu) {
    menu.add(R.menu.items);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsPanel(view, menu);
}

        //OPTIONS MENU STARTS HERE
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch(item.getItemId()){


    case R.id.search:

        Intent startSearch=new Intent(myFrag.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(startSearch);
        break;

        case R.id.login:
       // login.show();
            break;

        case R.id.settings:
           // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected settings", 
            break;

        case R.id.exit:

            break;
    default:
        break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

The switch case is used to select between items

Here is my items xml code in the menu folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
/>

   <item
    android:id="@+id/publish"
    android:title="@string/publish_"
    android:icon="@drawable/publish"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
/>

 <item
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:title="@string/login_"
    android:icon="@drawable/login"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
/>

  <item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:title="@string/settings_"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
/>


<item
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:title="@string/exit_"
    android:icon="@drawable/power"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
  />


  </menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add menu(not in menu-v11)

Select res folder, right click on it
New > Android Resource Directory > Resource Type = menu > Press Enter

There you are. Now you will see menu folder under res.

To add menu's xml inside menu
New > Menu Resource File > Name the file > Press Enter

it should be like this res/menu/items.xml